# how to copy all files from one location to another in linux

Tags: cp

I want to copy all the folders and files in the 
`/var/www/` directory to another directory `/media/magneto/`

How do I do this?

I tried this command

```
cp -pRiv /var/www/ /media/magneto/
```

that didn't work because it basically created a directory called `www` underneath magento and started copying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`cp -R /var/www /media/magneto` Avoid the extra forward slash at the end of the path name.

Or

you can navigate to the `/var` directory in terminal and then try

`cp -R www /media/magneto`

Comment: This did not work for me. It still copied over the "www" folder. I followed the last example, and even left off trailing slashes

Answer (score 2):

If the magneto directory exists, you can use the following command:

```
cp -R /var/www /media/magneto
```

If it doesn't already exist you can use the following command to create it:

```
rsync -av /var/www/ /media/magneto
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -pRiv /var/www/{*,.*} /media/magneto
```

and, dovetailing off Thomas' answer:

```
pushd /var/www; cp -R . /media/magneto; popd;
```

Comment: Will this not ignore hidden files?

Comment: @Jason - There ya go.  That should do it -- at least, it will work in bash, csh, and tcsh.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -R /var/www /media/magneto
```

This will copy www folder to  /media/magneto folder
Use below cmd:

```
cp -R /var/www/* /media/magneto
```

This will copy all the files and folder to /media/magneto folder from www folder